# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.update(sql) sometimes returns incorrect number of affected rows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, optimistic-locking

I have a production web site with the following environment:

- Rails 2.3.5
- MySQL Server 5.1.33
- Enterprise Ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [x86_64-linux]
- mysql gem 2.7
- Old version of BackgrounDRb plugin running on 4 different servers for background tasks, with 5 different workers each (*Ruby threads, not separate processes!*).

One of the BackgrounDRb workers processes the job queue using a variation of "optimistic locking":

```
    update_sql = "update jobs
                  set updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                      in_process = 1
                  where id = #{job.id} and in_process = 0"

    affected_rows = Job.connection.update(update_sql)
    captured_job = affected_rows > 0 ? Job.find(job.id) : nil
```

The code above tries to update the record with the given ID and with extra condition for in_process field. So if this same record was already updated by a different server/process then UPDATE statement would just return 0 (zero) and the job would not be processed simultaneously by 2 different servers.

**The problem is:** sometimes "Job.connection.update(update_sql)" returns 0 (zero) even when the record was actually updated! I was only able to find that out after a heavy logging was added to the code. It only happens in Production at night when we have a heavy load...

My guess is that mysql gem uses some global variable (class-variable) for affected_rows that is shared across all 5 threads of BackgrounDRb process, but I'm not sure. I was looking through the code of mysql gem and ActiveRecord, but I couldn't understand how it really works.

How could this happen?

**Update 2010-07-07:** We decided to not use threads for job processing - that'll solve all our problems: every job processor would be a separate process :)

Comment: I don't know how it happens, but I do know that it does happen.